# Reroute email to correct domain

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, whm

I am trying to send a mail to different domain name as my mail server is located on another domain. Therefore, whenever I try to send an email using `php mail` function then it consider as the local email mail and send it. However, I want to send it another domain. Lets say:

```
 $to='example@gmail.com' //this works 
 $to='example@mydomain.com' //this does not work.
```

When I checked it using the `WHM` I figured it out that it consider the emails as the local mail and hence the such email does not exist on my web domain so it disappears.

How can I reroute my emails to send it to correct domain ?

**Update**

I can see following error on WHM mail error logs:

> third_party: Domain where my mail server is located
>
> mydomain : current web domain.

```
 ravi@mydomain.com.au R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp: SMTP error from remote mail server
 after RCPT TO:<ravi@mydomain.com.au>: host mail.mydomain.com.au: 550-Verification failed 
 for <third_party@server.third_party.com.au>\n550-The mail server could not deliver mail to
 third_party@server.third_party.com.au. The account or domain may not exist, they may be 
 blacklisted, or missing the proper dns entries.\n550 Sender verify failed
```

---

Comment: what does the mydomain.com mx record point to ?

Comment: in WHM, change the name of your local email domain to something else and restart your email program / reboot

Comment: well, it is same as the mail domain. It was selected to send mail local and I changed it to 'Remote..' option and still no luck